# Solve "HTTP 510 Not Extended" Error

Tags: apache, http

My server fired every week a 510 HTTP error. After reboot the apache, the problem was solve. 
But this is more a workaround as a solution for this problem.

Any ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this status code is being set by Apache and not, e.g. PHP/Perl/Ruby/Java...? see also http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html#510_Extended and RFC 2774.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue , one of sites that im holding got the same story - many errors in firebug "510 Not extended" .

Checked configuration of apache and server , there was limit on numbers of connections and total outgoing traffic bandwidth .

## When put it to unlimited all working perfect when ,enabling limiting get this error, need to find the middle when it working good and there no "unlimited" for all traffic set.

The reason why we set this limiting was - one of the sites on server was raising traffic, up to limit of whole server - too much connections and outgoing traffic ...  we didnt find this site ,but added module that allow you manage traffic and connection limiting per site.

So in my opinion you have the same issue when one of the sites raising your traffic and you start get this error - you as you said restarting apache - and that solves this permanently.