# HTTP Status Code 510 usage

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I'm getting to know the http status codes and kind of stuck on the 510 Not Extended.

It's mentioned on many sites like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) but not under the unofficial codes. However when I read the [rfc2774](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2774) it's labelled 'Experimental'.

- So should I assume that it's (not?) used? Do any servers/sites support/use it?

I also wonder how the status code is supposed to work

- Do you use 510 only if the client attempted to send a Man or C-Man that is not supported by the server?

  - (**update**) It seems that the apache http server htaccess ErrorDocument returns `"A mandatory extension policy in the request is not accepted by the server for this resource."`
    [askapache.com](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html#510_Extended)
  - (**update**) OTOH `Servers can force the use of the HTTP Extension Framework by using the 510 "Not Extended" HTTP status code.` [Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383530)
- How does a server send back all the information necessary for the client to issue an extended request?

The rfc says

> The policy for accessing the resource has not been met in the
> request.  The server should send back all the information necessary
> for the client to issue an extended request. I**t is outside the scope
> of this specification to specify how the extensions inform the
> client.**

What does this mean?

I'd figure it worked something like

(Must use GET on resource /html and the extension "x")

```
HTTP/1.1 510 Extended
M-GET /html
Man : "http://www.company.com/extension"; ns=11
11-ext : "x"

HTTP/1.1 510 Extended
M-GET /html
C-Man : "http://www.company.com/extension"; ns=11
11-ext : "x"
Connection: C-Man, 11-ext
```

But section 6 says this

> A server MUST NOT include mandatory extension declarations in an HTTP
> response unless it is responding to a mandatory HTTP request whose
> definition allowed for the mandatory response or the server has some
> a priori knowledge that the recipient can handle the extended
> response. **A server MAY include optional extension declarations in
> any HTTP response (s**ee section 4).

As a note. I read that the "ext" and "c-ext" are not relevant here because

> The extension response header fields are exclusively intended to serve as
> extension acknowledgements, and can not carry any other information.

(**update**) Example 4 SOAP Using HTTP Extension Framework in [section 6.4 SOAP HTTP Examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383531) looks similar to my example?

```
M-POST /StockQuote HTTP/1.1
Man: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; ns=NNNN
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: nnnn
NNNN-SOAPAction: "http://electrocommerce.org/abc#MyMessage"

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Ext:
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: nnnn

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope...
```

Comment: It's marked experimental which means whiskey and gun slinging.  For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101042/solve-http-510-not-extended-error

Comment: Thx @RamblinRose, I followed the link in the link you gave and updated my question. I've seen that question, but couldn't understand it (I've found a few 510 questions when googling but I found them not helpful). I've also never heard the idiom 'whiskey and gun slinging' (neither has google?) are you saying that 'anyone can do whatever they want'?

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying.  The RFC seems slightly ambiguous in my opinion but I don't ponder with a ph.D. mindset.  This is probably the best use of the code I've seen https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383530  From everything I've gathered the client has to "know" about any given extension framework.